# ng-click in repeat tr, how to make it to go to the desired page?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, ui-sref

Here is my repeat table:

```
<tr ng-repeat="expenses in vm.expense | orderBy:'days'" 
     class="start-text" ng-click="location.path('/expense/{{expenses._id}}')">
```

I wanted it to go to `/expense/1234` but it does nothing when I click

I also have this button:

```
<a ui-sref="expense/new">
    <button class="start-expense-btn start-button" 
            style="width:120px;">NEW EXPENSE</button>
</a>
```

And that one works perfectly, goes to `/expense/` with the parameter new.

So how do I get `ui-sref` into that `ng-click` (if that is what I have to do).

Comment: use ui-sref instead of ng-click in the repeat table

Comment: you can really do that??  - I will try at once

Comment: nope, it had no effect at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a function inside the controller,

```
$scope.changeLocation = function(expense){
   var pathtoNavigate = "/expense/"+ expense.id;
   $location.path(pathtoNavigate);
}
```

and pass the expense in the ng-click function,

```
 ng-click="changeLocation(expenses)"
```

Comment: yes thats probably the only way (or the right way at least hehe)

Comment: Since I have to use it many places, im trying to do this: `ng-click="vm.changeLocations('expense/' + {{expenses._id}})"`

But then the link will be `http://localhost:8080/expense/%7B%7Bexpenses._id%7D%7D` - any ideas here?

Comment: never mind - I was being an idiot - didnt need the {{}} of cause haha